# Trimming a string in Teradata

Tags: teradata, trim

I have a table in Teradata with a particular column "location" like

```
location
Rockville County, TX 
Green River County, IL
Joliet County, CA
Jones County, FL
.
.
.
```

What I need to do is strip off everything after the county's name and turn the column into something like

```
location
Rockville
Green River 
Joliet 
Jones
```

I've been trying to use the function trim like

```
trim(trailing ' County' from location)
```

but it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `trim` function is used for removing whitespace.

You can use a combination of `index` and `substring`, e.g.:

```
select 
    'Green River County, IL' your_string
    , substring(your_string, 0, index(your_string, 'County')) your_desired_result
```

`index(target_string, string_to_find)` gives you the position of a string within another string

`substring(target_string, start_index, end_index)` allows you to pull out a specific part of a string

Answer (score 0):

This is the Standard SQL way:

```
substring(location from 0 for position(' County' in location))
```

In TD14 you might also use a regular expression:

```
regexp_substr(location, '.*(?= County)')
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Will implement it properly.